# Snow Leopard: MySQL doesn't start

Tags: mysql, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I have updated to Snow Leopard and I removed mysql by following this post: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,75256,255853#msg-255853

After that I have installed the mysql 64 bit community edition, but using the prefpane MySQL doesn't start.

Using the terminal gives us some more informations, but I don't know how to interpret them:

```
stefansmac:~ stefan$ cd /usr/local/mysql-5.1.42-osx10.5-x86_64/bin/
stefansmac:bin stefan$ sudo ./mysqld_safe
100105 13:56:35 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql-5.0.51b-osx10.5-x86//stefansmac.local.err'.
100105 13:56:35 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql-5.0.51b-osx10.5-x86/
100105 13:56:35 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql-5.0.51b-osx10.5-x86//stefansmac.local.pid ended
```

Best regards

Comment: Please post the contents of the error log (/usr/local/mysql-5.0.51b-osx10.5-x86//stefansmac.local.err) (possibly suitably abbreviated) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: The file /usr/local/mysql-5.0.51b-osx10.5-x86//stefansmac.local.err is empty.

Comment: What happens when you try to launch it with root user ?

Answer (score 1):

After adding the /usr/local/mysql/bin path to PATH I get the following error when executing ./mysqld

```
100105 14:14:11 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-5.0.51b-osx10.5-x86/ is case insensitive
100105 14:14:11 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

100105 14:14:11 [ERROR] Aborting

100105 14:14:11 [Note] ./mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: What happens when you read the "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root? The manual says you have to specify a user for mysqld to run as when running as root, it will not run as root.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `/usr/local/mysql-5.0.51b-osx10.5-x86/` directory is owned by the `mysql` user. That is: `sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/mysql-5.0.51b-osx10.5-x86/`